# Возможность закрыть окно JInternalFrame

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;


public class TreeExample extends JInternalFrame 
{
    private JTree tree;
    public TreeExample()
    {
        //create the root node
        DefaultMutableTreeNode plenki = new        DefaultMutableTreeNode("Номенклатура");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode chehli = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Чехлы");
        //create the child nodes
        DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("первые");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode fruitNode = new  DefaultMutableTreeNode("вторые");

        //add the child nodes to the root node
        plenki.add(vegetableNode);
        vegetableNode.add(chehli);
       // plenki.add(fruitNode);
        plenki.add(fruitNode);

        //create the tree by passing in the root node
        tree = new JTree(plenki);
        add(tree);


        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("JTree Example");       
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
       // this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой у вас вопрос?

Comment: Правильнее исправлять вопрос кнопкой "править", а не создавать новый. В любом случае останется только один (с).